# Perturbation test for a real plant

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis, control-systems

How should we conduct a perturbation test for an LTI unknown system by perturbing the input to see the output response i.e. How many different perturbation step size should be given to the input?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to include the physical system description.  I had a friend who had to put in a control system for a large radar antenna; which was perfectly capable of tearing itself apart if commanded incorrectly.  Touchy!  He wrapped a very slow control loop around the antenna to position and stabilize it, and then he injected a _very_ low level of noise and did a cross-correlation of input versus output.  Worked out fine.   HP/Agilent made an instrument that was designed for this type of analysis.  The point is, the methods vary with the application/reality.